# how to get HTML5 Application Cache Status by Selenium/Java

Tags: java, html, caching, selenium

how to get HTML5 Application Cache Status by Selenium/Java

For Selenium/Java programming, how can the Selenium/Java get the status of the HTML5 Application cache status? I tried below, but it didn't work. "cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.html5.ApplicationCache.."

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.html5.AppCacheStatus;
import org.openqa.selenium.html5.ApplicationCache;

public class Html5AppCache {

    public void testHTML5LocalStorage() throws Exception {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryhtml5_html_manifest.htm");

        AppCacheStatus status = ((ApplicationCache) (driver)).getStatus();

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you googled this? Java is serverside and application cache is client side..

Comment: read the [AppCacheStatus](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/html5/AppCacheStatus.html) and [ApplicationCache](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/html5/ApplicationCache.html) implementation before moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting the short to AppCacheStatus object below, hence the error.

```
  AppCacheStatus status = ((ApplicationCache) (driver)).getStatus();
```

[ApplicationCache](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/html5/ApplicationCache.html#getStatus%28%29) is an interface so you have to write your own version of getStatus method.

You may want to get the cache status using the JavaScriptExecutor. Hope that helps.

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
long cacheStatus = (long) jsExecutor.executeScript("return  window.applicationCache.status;");
System.out.println(cacheStatus);
```